# excel.link R package: Error when referring to cell by object, not directly naming cell

Tags: r, excel

I'm trying out excel.link and it has the functionality I need when I'm directly referring to a cell via the command line or a script, eg `xlrc[h4] <- 500` sets cell H4 to 500 (I just switch over to Excel and check). This works, but if I try to set the cell as an object (eg `k <- 'H4'` ) then refer to that object `xlrc[k] <- 500` , `I get Error: Exception Returned`. I'm trying out `excel.link` because I need to be able to do what-if scenarios on a spreadsheet with thousands of iterations, so I need to be able to not hand-type in cell references every time! Where did I go wrong?